# Using awk/cut in bash to strip space and get value

Tags: bash, svn

I'm trying to get the value in the first column as shown below using awk or cut but I don't seem to get it.

```
  7  ?                    Jun 18 23:31 test3folder1/
```

I only need the number 7 in the above output to store in a variable. How do I do this? The above is the output of the "svn ls" command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

awk '{print $1}'

'awk' strips by one or several consecutive delimiters (space in your case), while 'cut' always strips by single delimeter.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn ls -v | awk '{print $1}'
```

And I do recommend that you `man awk` and play with it a bit, to get a feeling of its functionality.

Comment: `svn ls -v | awk '{print $1}' | xargs rm`, if you want to delete it.